# How to find a commit by its hash?

Tags: git

I need to find a commit in Git by a given hash, SHA. For example, if I have the "a2c25061" hash, and I need to get the author and the committer of this commit.

What is the command to get that?

Answer (score 580):

Just use the following command

```
git show a2c25061
```

Comment: Also good will be `git log a2c25061 -n 1`. It will show only info about commit, without diff.

Comment: `git show a2c25061 --stat` works the same and is easier to remember

Comment: Off topic, but may be very useful for those looking to checkout a commit by hash, without knowing e.g. what branch an old commit was made on, simply by using `git checkout a2c25061`

Comment: Note that `git log -p -1 <commit_hash>` is **exactly identical to** `git show <commit_hash>`.

Comment: `git show a2c25061 -s` is an even shorter way to suppress the diff output.

Comment: Beware of rewritten commits. Even if the commit sourcetree is not changed, you won't find the commit. Because of lack of the hash for the sourcetree in a commit additionally to the hash for entire commit.

Answer (score 73):

```
git log -1 --format="%an %ae%n%cn %ce" a2c25061
```

The [Pretty Formats section of the `git show` documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html#_pretty_formats) contains

> - `format:<string>`
>
> The `format:<string>` format allows you to specify which information you want to show. It works a little bit like printf format, with the notable exception that you get a newline with `%n` instead of `\n` …
>
> The placeholders are:
>
> - `%an`: author name
> - `%ae`: author email
> - `%cn`: committer name
> - `%ce`: committer email

Comment: not directly related to the question, but maybe it's worth mentioning that `%s` gives you the commit message

Answer (score 29):

There are two ways to do this.

**1. providing the SHA of the commit you want to see to git log**

`git log -p a2c25061`

Where `-p` is short for patch

**2. use git show**

`git show a2c25061`

The output for both commands will be:

- the commit
- the author
- the date
- the commit message
- the patch information