# How to check with Git before merge if the merge is necessary? ("Already up-to-date.")

Tags: git, shell, git-merge

In a deployment pipeline I'm checking out master in a clean clone (which is the target) and then
I merge the revision into it to update it.

```
git checkout master
git merge "${revision}"
```

As git has a pre-merge check it then tells in my scenario:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

when the revision was already merged.

How can I find out previous to the merge command, that this ("Already up-to-date") is the case, so that I can exit the pipeline early as there is nothing anymore to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor $revision master || git merge $revision
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one is straight forward, I'll put onto the run, let's see what breaks ^^

Comment: Short answer: nothing. I needed an inverse test (if already merged, break the build with a message saying it's already merged), which was straight forward. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

You can check output of below command

```
git log --oneline devlop..origin/master
```

this will show all the commits which are in origin/master but not in devlop branch.

if there is no output, then all changes are merged
otherwise origin/master needs to be merged into devlop branch

Answer (score 0):

you can try using

```
git branch --merged
```

which will check list it for being merged already as explained on 
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branch-Management

so you can checkout your revision as a temporary branch, check if it has been merged and remove it afterwards.

Comment: The `${revision}` I have is not a branch name but the full hash ref. There is no branch for it. Is that a problem for git branch -- merged?

Comment: Just seeing your update, temp branch might be OKish, but can't this be checked for a revision as well?

Comment: no, as explained in my answer - you can create branch from revision and use it to do the check.

Comment: what optionally comes to my mind is you can use git log as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167335/find-commit-by-hash-sha-in-git and find your particular revision.  just have in mind this will not work when your revision has other previous commits which is why I prefer --merged over searching the log

Comment: Alright, I can follow so far what you suggest here, temporary branch name is required so I can keep being on the master branch. Let me fiddle with it. I think this needs some command lines.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `git diff ${revision} --name-status`. If nothing is printed, then there are no differences between versions and no merge is needed.